# Convert IP address to dot syntax from unsigned long integer in iOS

Tags: iphone, c, ios, ip, inet

I'm retrieving an IP address as an unsigned long integer via JSON. I'm trying to then convert this back to human readable form, ie xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.

Example of what I receive in JSON:

```
"ip": 704210705
```

I'm struggling a bit as C was never my forte. I'm getting an EXC Bad Access error on the below:

```
unsigned long int addr = [[user objectForKey:@"ip"] unsignedLongValue];
struct in_addr *remoteInAddr = (struct in_addr *)addr;
char *sRemoteInAddr = inet_ntoa(*remoteInAddr);
```

I get the error on the char line (3).

Can anyone give me any advice?

Comment: What error do you get on line 3?

Comment: The original problem is really that you have a json that sends ips using integers. You'll have to support IPv6 sooner or later and that won't be pretty to change.

Comment: I agree... alas it's not in my control :(

Comment: inet_ntoa takes a in_addr struct, not an integer.  Also, can you provide both the unsignedLongValue you get from from the JCON and the human readable form of it?

Comment: added the JSON snippet above. The 'ip' object is part of a user object (An NSDictionary in the above code)

Comment: presumably ip 704210705 == 41.249.103.17, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
struct in_addr a;
a.s_addr = addr;
char *remote = inet_ntoa(a);
```

note that the memory pointed to by `remote` is statically allocated in libc. Therefore, further calls to `inet_ntoa` will overwrite the previous result.

To get the string properly into obj-c land, use

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:remote];
```

Or, putting everything together:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa((struct in_addr){addr})];
```

Comment: btw I get an error on a.s_addr = addr; - Use of undeclared identifier 'a'

Comment: This works (when you fix struct in_addr a;), however the IP address is wrong that it returns. This suggests my addr is not being assigned correctly... Any ideas?

Comment: Is it inverted (d.c.b.a instead of a.b.c.d) ? If so your IP is in host order. Use a.s_addr = htonl(addr) to get it back in what your OS expects.

Comment: whoops, typo in the first line, fixed.

Comment: `inet_ntoa` is deprecated and not included in modern standards. It's not thread-safe and uses an internal static buffer. It would be better to use `inet_ntop`.

Answer (score 0):

[Swift version, with extension](https://gist.github.com/cybertk/61dbc56595723efb7fac).

```
extension UInt32 {

    public func IPv4String() -> String {

        let ip = self

        let byte1 = UInt8(ip & 0xff)
        let byte2 = UInt8((ip>>8) & 0xff)
        let byte3 = UInt8((ip>>16) & 0xff)
        let byte4 = UInt8((ip>>24) & 0xff)

        return "\(byte1).\(byte2).\(byte3).\(byte4)"
    }
}
```

Then

```
print(UInt32(704210705).IPv4String())
```